# Editing Comment Issue

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed when I go to edit a comment from a typo or whatever, I get back `[object Object]`.

[image]

**Question:** Am I the only one affected by this and what is it or what does it mean?

I already closed the browser and re-opened but I'm using the usual Chrome browser I normally use and I never noticed this before. Rather than troubleshooting, I wanted to post and ask in case it's a bug or something already discovered.

Comment: It's not just you. [Edit comment yields \[object Object\] instead of comment text](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/314305)

Comment: Happens in the latest Firefox as well.

Comment: [Fixed now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314309/295684)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [@Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel)
>
> This is my fault, the fix is live now for MSE, building on the
>   network.
>
> In working on
>   [Keyboard-only users cannot flag comments in the new comment flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313761/keyboard-only-users-cannot-flag-comments-in-the-new-comment-flag-dialog/314306#314306),
>   I needed access to the event that showed the flagging dialog, so I
>   updated the comment UI hooks to pass in the event as the first
>   parameter.
>
> This was fine fo the various hooks, upvote, flag, etc, except for
>   edit, because the edit hook already had a parameter defined
>   `textOverride`.  So the event that was passed in was treated as a text
>   override and replaced the edit text.
>
> <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314305/edit-comment-yields-object-object-instead-of-comment-text/314309#314309)</sub>